# Threading function block main not all the time

Tags: python, multithreading, nonblocking

I am working on a project in which I have a main class which create a thread for execute a very long function whereas the main class (my GUI) will continue to be available for displaying some information during the execution of this long function. So I found on Stack Overflow a way to do it:

```
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, QtCore, QtGui
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication
import threading
import sys
import time
from PyQt5.QtCore import QObject, pyqtSignal


class Ui_SaftMainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, SaftMainWindow):
        SaftMainWindow.setObjectName("SaftMainWindow")
        SaftMainWindow.resize(178, 284)
        icon = QtGui.QIcon()
        icon.addPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap(":/logo/img_Logo-E.png"), QtGui.QIcon.Normal, QtGui.QIcon.Off)
        SaftMainWindow.setWindowIcon(icon)
        self.gridLayout = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(SaftMainWindow)
        self.gridLayout.setObjectName("gridLayout")
        self.frame_all_pb = QtWidgets.QFrame(SaftMainWindow)
        self.frame_all_pb.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(160, 0))
        self.frame_all_pb.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(160, 16777215))
        self.frame_all_pb.setObjectName("frame_all_pb")
        self.gridLayout_7 = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(self.frame_all_pb)
        self.gridLayout_7.setObjectName("gridLayout_7")
        self.pb_stop_simu = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.frame_all_pb)
        self.pb_stop_simu.setText("STOP")
        self.gridLayout_7.addWidget(self.pb_stop_simu, 5, 0, 1, 1)
        self.pb_start_simu = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.frame_all_pb)
        self.pb_start_simu.setObjectName("pb_start_simu")
        self.pb_start_simu.setText("START")
        self.gridLayout_7.addWidget(self.pb_start_simu, 4, 0, 1, 1)
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.frame_all_pb, 0, 0, 1, 1)

        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(SaftMainWindow)


class Solver(QObject, object):
    data_changed = pyqtSignal(str, int)

    def __init__(self):
        # Call init function of QObject class for pyQt signal
        QObject.__init__(self)


    def init_parameters(self, input_files, **keys):
        print("Some initialisation")

    def time_step(self):
        # Function with Fortran call
        print("Fortran function")

    def transient_solve(self, arg):
        print("starting")
        t = threading.currentThread()
        i = 1
        while getattr(t, "do_run", True):
            print("working on " + str(i))
            i += 1
            time.sleep(5)
        print("Stopping as you wish.")


class GuiHandler:
    def __init__(self, gui, main_window,):
        # Declarations
        self.gui = gui
        self.main_window = main_window

        self.gui.setupUi(self.main_window)
        self.gui.pb_start_simu.clicked.connect(self.pb_start_simu_clicked)
        self.gui.pb_stop_simu.clicked.connect(self.pb_stop_simu_clicked)

        # Create instance of the second class
        app = Solver()

        # Connect signal to emit signal from second class to ihm later
        app.data_changed.connect(self.myfunction)

        # Initialize some parameters of my second class
        app.init_parameters("", json_file="", output_file="")

        # Create thread object
        self.t = threading.Thread(target=app.transient_solve, args=("task",))

    def pb_start_simu_clicked(self):
        print("Start thread")
        self.t.start()

    def pb_stop_simu_clicked(self):
        print("Stop thread")
        self.t.do_run = False
        self.t.join()

    def myfunction(self, string="this_is_a_test", integer=0):
        print(str(string))
        print(str(integer))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    handler = GuiHandler(Ui_SaftMainWindow(), QtWidgets.QWidget())
    handler.main_window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

This simple example works. But, when I replace the sleep by a call to a bigger function (the time_step function which call a Fortran file compiled as Python, the GUI function is blocked)

Any idea if it is linked to my way to create and start the thread or any idea about what I have to check/find to make works my code?

I can't give you another code sample for now.

Comment: You are starting the thread correctly, what do you mean exactly by "the main thread is blocked"? the `.join()` call is supposed to block until `doit()` finishes

Comment: In real I have a GUI, the start button call t.start(), the stop button call the "do_run=False" and join functions. But with my long function I can't click on the stop button whereas with this simple example I can continue to use the GUI after starting the thread

Comment: @MathieuGauquelin then provide a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) based on your actual code, and remember that GUI frameworks are event driven, should *never* be blocked in *any* way (no while loops, no `time.sleep` etc) and *no* direct access to UI elements is allowed from external threads.

Comment: [sigh] the curse of join strikes again:(   In GUI apps, it's best to avoid join by using thread pools or dedicated app-lifetime threads that are only stopped by the OS at process termination.  In non-GUI apps, it's also best to avoid join but, due in part to the appalling pthreads library, it's difficult to deflect the momentum of create/terminate/join:(

Comment: I focus the problem, all is working except when in my function I call a Fortran code compiled on a pyd Python file. I can give you another example because of this Fortran code which is "protected"

Comment: I edited my answer with an example (and my architecture code in the same time)

Comment: I find a solution, adding '!f2py: threadsafe' in the fortran code (found on this website: https://f2py-users.cens.ioc.narkive.com/F5sfdYNP/threading-with-f2py&sa=D&source=hangouts&ust=1612346740108000&usg=AFQjCNHncxp_3Pm4ndyKR1VuidvNeKl_vA)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find a solution, adding `!f2py: threadsafe` in the fortran code.